# How can I create a boost tuple which depends on the typename of tuple?

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming

I'd like to create tuple of type which depends on the name of that type.

Maybe example would clarify my problem:

```
//T would be boost::tuples::tuple<int, int, ...>
template <typename T>
T generate()
{
    typedef T GT;
    typedef boost::tuples::element<0,GT>::type tt0;
    typedef boost::tuples::element<1,GT>::type tt1;
    typedef boost::tuples::element<2,GT>::type tt2;
    if(tt3==null_type)
        return boost::tuples::make_tuple<tt0,tt1>(static_cast<tt0>(1), static_cast<tt1>(2));
    else
        return boost::tuples::make_tuple<tt0, tt1, tt2>(static_cast<tt0>(1), static_cast<tt1>(2), ...);
}
```

EDIT:
I've found nice way, **template recursion**.
Problem solved.

Comment: And those errors are...?

Comment: A more liberal application of `typename` could get you what you want.

Comment: @Noah What exactly you mean by 'more liberal application of typename'?

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef typename oost::tuples::element<0,GT>::type tt0;
```

...

```
if(tt3==null_type)
```

you cant check types likes this, use `mpl::if_` instead

```
        return boost::tuples::make_tuple<tt0,tt1>(static_cast<tt0>(1), static_cast<tt1>(2));
    else
        return boost::tuples::make_tuple<tt0, tt1, tt2>(static_cast<tt0>(1), static_cast<tt1>(2), ...);
```

are you trying to remove null_type?  Just use `boost::fusion::remove`.

Here is another solution:

```
template <typename T>
tuple<tt0,tt1> 
generate(typename enable_if<is_same<tt3, null_type> >::type* = 0) {
    typedef typename boost::tuples::element<0,T>::type tt0;
    typedef typename boost::tuples::element<1,T>::type tt1;
     return make_tuple(tt0(1), tt1(1));
}
```

similary for other case.

notice: `boost::enable_if`, `boost::is_same`

Comment: 'if' is not the problem,  removing either.
Just want to create tuple depending on tuple model.

Comment: @bua you cant compare types using if statement, eg `int == double` is incorrect.  see update.

Comment: Yes, i understand that but it's not about comparsion at all, we can throw out this if and still I can't create variable number of items in tuple in this function.